# Send Varnishinformation with http response

Tags: server, typo3, httpresponse, varnish

I want to send information about the varnish server with the `http` response of e.g a picture. Is there any way to do that?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you explain how is this related to TYPO3?

Answer (score 0):

Any info/header/variable readable in `vcl_deliver` or `vcl_synth` (Varnish 4 in this case) can be sent as response headers.

```
sub vcl_deliver {
    set resp.http.X-Varnish-Server = server.ip;
}
```